# Reverse format carbon date

Tags: php, php-carbon

Is it possible to ***'unformat'*** formatted date in carbon?

Something like:

```
$date = '2018-06-01';
$date->format("F/Y"); --> June/2018
```

Is it possible to reverse `June/2018 --> 2018-06`?

Comment: Use createFromFormat()

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $date->format("F/Y");// June/2018
```

If you already have the carbon object instance and you want to get 2018-06 you can straightaway use but I suppose this isn't the case and you want the obtained string June/2018 to get converted to 2018-06, you can do this by the help of `createFromFormat()` method which is powerful enough to convert any date/time format to any other date/time format provided you know the source and the destination format

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('F/Y', $result)->format('Y-m'); //2018-06
```